# I need to create a annotation which can be used to log returned value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj

For a use case, We need to create custom annotation which will log return values of methods which are annotated with this annotation.
For input arg its quite simple but how to create for return value?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Around` and log the result:

```
@Aspect
public class YourAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(YourAnnotation) && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object returnObject = null;
        try {
            returnObject = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            // You may want to log this
            throw throwable;
        }
        // log returnObject here...
        return returnObject;
    }
}
```